# How to correct View [welcome] not found. with laravel on a shared host

Tags: php, laravel

i host a laravel application on a shared host but it saying view not find. so i clear my cache with

```
Route::get('/cmd', function () {
    chdir('../');
    $dir =  getcwd();
    print_r($dir);
    $cmd = shell_exec ('php artisan cache:clear');
    return $cmd;
});
```

that code is what i used to clear my cache now the whole system is just showing a blank page

Comment: Make sure there is the `/resources/views/welcome.blade.php` view. If this view exists, please show how you're trying to render it.

Comment: also check error logs

Comment: it is working fine with local host it  is `Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');`
WeclomeController
`return view('welcome');`

Comment: it is not working to any of this, i  located my bootsrap\cache\config,php i found out the dir is not pointing correctly, line 2 of the stack view says `FileViewFinder->finInPaths('Welcome, array(home4\\username\\MainFolder\\resources\\views)) in FileViewFinder.php line 79` i have tried to point to the dir but to no avail

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix i have check the error_log file and after the blank erroe page i got back to the file not found error